# Difference between src_mask and src_key_padding_mask

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model

I am having a difficult time in understanding transformers. Everything is getting clear bit by bit but one thing that makes my head scratch is
what is the difference between src_mask and src_key_padding_mask which is passed as an argument in forward function in both encoder layer and decoder layer.

https://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torch/nn/modules/transformer.html#Transformer

Comment: from the official pytorch forum: `The src_mask is just a square matrix which is used to filter the attention weights. ... src_key_padding_mask is more like a padding marker, which masks a specific tokens in the src sequence (a.k.a. the entire column/row of the attention matrix is set to '-inf').` https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/nn-transformer-explaination/53175/5

Comment: another post https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/transformer-difference-between-src-mask-and-src-key-padding-mask/84024 from the official pytorch forum.

Comment: yet another one: https://www.reddit.com/r/pytorch/comments/okfh2k/transformer_difference_between_src_mask_and_src/

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62399243/transformerencoder-with-a-padding-mask

Comment: perhaps reading the docs for MHA is the best...? https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html#torch.nn.MultiheadAttention

Answer (score 39):

## Difference between src_mask and src_key_padding_mask

The general thing is to notice the difference between the use of the tensors `_mask` vs `_key_padding_mask`.
Inside the transformer when attention is done we usually get an squared intermediate tensor with all the comparisons
of size `[Tx, Tx]` (for the input to the encoder), `[Ty, Ty]` (for the shifted output - one of the inputs to the decoder)
and `[Ty, Tx]` (for the memory mask - the attention between output of encoder/memory and input to decoder/shifted output).

So we get that this are the uses for each of the masks in the transformer
(note the notation from the pytorch docs is as follows where `Tx=S is the source sequence length`
(e.g. max of input batches),
`Ty=T is the target sequence length` (e.g. max of target length),
`B=N is the batch size`,
`D=E is the feature number`):

1. src_mask `[Tx, Tx] = [S, S]` – the additive mask for the src sequence (optional).
   This is applied when doing `atten_src + src_mask`. I'm not sure of an example input - see tgt_mask for an example
   but the typical use is to add `-inf` so one could mask the src_attention that way if desired.
   If a ByteTensor is provided, the non-zero positions are not allowed to attend while the zero positions will be unchanged.
   If a BoolTensor is provided, positions with True is not allowed to attend while False values will be unchanged.
   If a FloatTensor is provided, it will be added to the attention weight.
2. tgt_mask `[Ty, Ty] = [T, T]` – the additive mask for the tgt sequence (optional).
   This is applied when doing `atten_tgt + tgt_mask`. An example use is the diagonal to avoid the decoder from cheating.
   So the tgt is right shifted, the first tokens are start of sequence token embedding SOS/BOS and thus the first
   entry is zero while the remaining. See concrete example at the appendix.
   If a ByteTensor is provided, the non-zero positions are not allowed to attend while the zero positions will be unchanged.
   If a BoolTensor is provided, positions with True is not allowed to attend while False values will be unchanged.
   If a FloatTensor is provided, it will be added to the attention weight.
3. memory_mask `[Ty, Tx] = [T, S]`– the additive mask for the encoder output (optional).
   This is applied when doing `atten_memory + memory_mask`.
   Not sure of an example use but as previously, adding `-inf` sets some of the attention weight to zero.
   If a ByteTensor is provided, the non-zero positions are not allowed to attend while the zero positions will be unchanged.
   If a BoolTensor is provided, positions with True is not allowed to attend while False values will be unchanged.
   If a FloatTensor is provided, it will be added to the attention weight.
4. src_key_padding_mask `[B, Tx] = [N, S]` – the ByteTensor mask for src keys per batch (optional).
   Since your src usually has different lengths sequences it's common to remove the padding vectors
   you appended at the end.
   For this you specify the length of each sequence per example in your batch.
   See concrete example in appendix.
   If a ByteTensor is provided, the non-zero positions are not allowed to attend while the zero positions will be unchanged.
   If a BoolTensor is provided, positions with True is not allowed to attend while False values will be unchanged.
   If a FloatTensor is provided, it will be added to the attention weight.
5. tgt_key_padding_mask `[B, Ty] = [N, t]` – the ByteTensor mask for tgt keys per batch (optional).
   Same as previous.
   See concrete example in appendix.
   If a ByteTensor is provided, the non-zero positions are not allowed to attend while the zero positions will be unchanged.
   If a BoolTensor is provided, positions with True is not allowed to attend while False values will be unchanged.
   If a FloatTensor is provided, it will be added to the attention weight.
6. memory_key_padding_mask `[B, Tx] = [N, S]` – the ByteTensor mask for memory keys per batch (optional).
   Same as previous.
   See concrete example in appendix.
   If a ByteTensor is provided, the non-zero positions are not allowed to attend while the zero positions will be unchanged.
   If a BoolTensor is provided, positions with True is not allowed to attend while False values will be unchanged.
   If a FloatTensor is provided, it will be added to the attention weight.

## Appendix

Examples from pytorch tutorial (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/translation_transformer.html):

### 1 src_mask example

```
    src_mask = torch.zeros((src_seq_len, src_seq_len), device=DEVICE).type(torch.bool)
```

returns a tensor of booleans of size `[Tx, Tx]`:

```
tensor([[False, False, False,  ..., False, False, False],
         ...,
        [False, False, False,  ..., False, False, False]])
```

## 2 tgt_mask example

```
    mask = (torch.triu(torch.ones((sz, sz), device=DEVICE)) == 1)
    mask = mask.transpose(0, 1).float()
    mask = mask.masked_fill(mask == 0, float('-inf'))
    mask = mask.masked_fill(mask == 1, float(0.0))
```

generates the diagonal for the right shifted output which the input to the decoder.

```
tensor([[0., -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf,
         -inf, -inf, -inf],
        [0., 0., -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf,
         -inf, -inf, -inf],
        [0., 0., 0., -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf,
         -inf, -inf, -inf],
         ...,
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
         0., 0., -inf],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
         0., 0., 0.]])
```

usually the right shifted output has the BOS/SOS at the beginning and it's the tutorial gets the right shift simply
by appending that BOS/SOS at the front and then triming the last element with `tgt_input = tgt[:-1, :]`.

## 3 _padding

The padding is just to mask the padding at the end.
The src padding is usually the same as the memory padding.
The tgt has it's own sequences and thus it's own padding.
Example:

```
    src_padding_mask = (src == PAD_IDX).transpose(0, 1)
    tgt_padding_mask = (tgt == PAD_IDX).transpose(0, 1)
    memory_padding_mask = src_padding_mask
```

Output:

```
tensor([[False, False, False,  ...,  True,  True,  True],
        ...,
        [False, False, False,  ...,  True,  True,  True]])
```

note that a `False` means there is no padding token there (so yes use that value in the transformer forward pass) and a `True` means that there is a padding token (so masked it out so the transformer pass forward does not get affected).

---

The answers are sort of spread around but I found only these 3 references being useful
(the separate layers docs/stuff wasn't very useful honesty):

- long tutorial: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/translation_transformer.html
- MHA docs: https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html#torch.nn.MultiheadAttention
- transformer docs: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Transformer.html

Comment: For case 3 which mask should we provide if they are the same? What is the difference between the memory and src padding masks?

Comment: @EvanZamir I don't want to give general statements because I do want to encourage research creativity in how models are used (and this case masks). That being said, the memory is usually the embedded src (from the transformer encoder) and thus usually shares the same mask as the src (both `src_mask` and `src_key_padding_mask `). For your case if your input is the same as your output (e.g. an autoencoder) then you can use the same mask (i.e. create one vector and assign it to both variables `tgt_padding_mask  = src_padding_mask`). If you tell me what tasks your solving to help more.

Comment: I'm essentially building a model like word2vec but using just the Transformer Encoder module. So each sample is let's say up to 512 tokens but some samples could be much less and then have padding tokens obviously. Like BERT I replace 15% of tokens with a mask token and then try to predict the missing tokens. So I'm wondering now what mask I could use with the pad tokens. It seems like `src_key_padding_mask`? Do I just fill it with 1's and 0's?

Comment: @EvanZamir the `_key_padding_mask` - as used in the concrete print statement of my answer - shows that if there is a `True` then you are telling the pytorch transformer layer that there is a pad token there so it ignores it. I don't believe it actually matters what the content of the pad token is as long as you feed in this mask correctly. Anything with a `True` will be ignored and anything with a `False` will not. I added a few more comments to my answer (I suggest you to read them). In short, **focus on making the mask right** and your batch of sequences will be processed correctly.

Comment: Hi @CharlieParker thanks for detail comment. I have just one one question if `src_mask` is going to contain `False` values only then whats the use of it? as you wrote `while False values will be unchanged`

Comment: @maq I believe it's because you are feeding entire tensors to an API that expects entire tensors. This is because the pytorch API receives tensors to speed up with GPUs, so when GPU computations are done, it knows in the GPU code what to change and what not to change for you. It's so pytorch is able to function and be compatible with cuda (is my guess).

Comment: @CharlieParker I have the same question for `src_mask`. It feels like `src_mask` can be computed from `src_key_padding_mask` by doing N times of "outer products" on the padding mask. Otherwise what other purpose does `src_mask` have other than marking the paddings in the square attention matrix?

Answer (score 9):

To give a small example, consider I want to build a sequential recommender i.e., given the items the users have purchased till time 't' predict the next item at 't+1'

```
u1 - [i1, i2, i7]
u2 - [i2, i5]
u3 - [i6, i7, i1, i2]
```

For this task, I could use a transformer where I would make the sequence equal length by padding it with 0's on left.

```
u1 - [0,  i1, i2, i7]
u2 - [0,  0,  i2, i5]
u3 - [i6, i7, i1, i2]
```

I will use key_padding_mask to tell PyTorch that 0's shd be ignored.
Now, consider user `u3` where given `[i6]` I want to predict `[i7]` and later given `[i6, i7]` I want to predict `[i1]` i.e., I want causal attention, such that the attention doesn't peep into the future elements. For this, I will use attn_mask. Hence for user `u3` attn_mask will be like

```
[[True, False, False, False],
 [True, True , False, False],
 [True, True , True , False]
 [True, True , True , True ]]
```

Comment: So for the padding you would use `src_key_padding_mask`?

Comment: yes if I am padding then I will use a 2D boolean matrix called src_key_padding_mask

Answer (score 7):

I must say PyTorch implementations are a bit confusing as it contains too many mask parameters. But I can shed light on the two mask parameters that you are referring to. Both `src_mask` and `src_key_padding_mask` is used in the `MultiheadAttention` mechanism. According to the documentation of [MultiheadAttention](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html#torch.nn.MultiheadAttention):

> key_padding_mask – if provided, specified padding elements in the key will be ignored by the attention.
>
> attn_mask – 2D or 3D mask that prevents attention to certain positions.

As you know from the paper, [Attention is all you need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762), MultiheadAttention is used in both Encoder and Decoder. However, in Decoder, there are two types of MultiheadAttention. One is called `Masked MultiheadAttention` and another one is the regular `MultiheadAttention`. To accommodate both these techniques, PyTorch uses the above mentioned two parameters in their MultiheadAttention implementation.

So, long story short-

- `attn_mask` and `key_padding_mask` is used in Encoder's `MultiheadAttention` and Decoder's `Masked MultiheadAttention`.
- `memory_mask`  is used in Decoder's `MultiheadAttention` mechanism as pointed out [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/ec5d579929b2c56418aacaec0874b92937d095a4/torch/nn/modules/transformer.py#L124-L127).

Looking into the implementation of [MultiheadAttention](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/11f1014c05b902d3eef0fe01a7c432f818c2bdfe/torch/nn/functional.py#L3854) might help you.

As you can see from [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/11f1014c05b902d3eef0fe01a7c432f818c2bdfe/torch/nn/functional.py#L4110) and [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/11f1014c05b902d3eef0fe01a7c432f818c2bdfe/torch/nn/functional.py#L4117), first `src_mask` is used to block specific positions from attending and then `key_padding_mask` is used to block attending to pad tokens.

**Note.** Answer updated based on @michael-jungo's comment.

Comment: The two points under *long story short* are not correct. Firstly, an `attn_mask` and a `key_padding_mask` are used in the self-attention (enc-enc and dec-dec) as well as the encoder-decoder attention (enc-dec). Secondly, PyTorch [doesn't use the `src_mask` in the decoder, but rather the `memory_mask`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/ec5d579929b2c56418aacaec0874b92937d095a4/torch/nn/modules/transformer.py#L124-L127) (they are often the same, but separate in the API).  `src_mask` and `src_key_padding_mask` belong to the encoder's self-attention. The last sentence summarises it quite well

Comment: @wasi can you address the comment by Michael and correct your answer if it's incorrect?