# TransformerEncoder with a padding mask

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model, attention-model

I'm trying to implement torch.nn.TransformerEncoder with a src_key_padding_mask not equal to none. Imagine the input is of the shape `src = [20, 95]` and the binary padding mask has the shape `src_mask = [20, 95]`, 1 in the position of padded tokens and 0 for other positions. I make a transformer encoder with 8 layers, each of which contain an attention with 8 heads and hidden dimension 256:

```
layer=torch.nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(256, 8, 256, 0.1)
encoder=torch.nn.TransformerEncoder(layer, 6)
embed=torch.nn.Embedding(80000, 256)
src=torch.randint(0, 1000, (20, 95))
src = emb(src)
src_mask = torch.randint(0,2,(20, 95))
output =  encoder(src, src_mask)
```

But I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-107-31bf7ab8384b> in <module>
----> 1 output =  encoder(src, src_mask)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    545             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    546         else:
--> 547             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    548         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    549             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/transformer.py in forward(self, src, mask, src_key_padding_mask)
    165         for i in range(self.num_layers):
    166             output = self.layers[i](output, src_mask=mask,
--> 167                                     src_key_padding_mask=src_key_padding_mask)
    168 
    169         if self.norm:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    545             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    546         else:
--> 547             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    548         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    549             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/transformer.py in forward(self, src, src_mask, src_key_padding_mask)
    264         """
    265         src2 = self.self_attn(src, src, src, attn_mask=src_mask,
--> 266                               key_padding_mask=src_key_padding_mask)[0]
    267         src = src + self.dropout1(src2)
    268         src = self.norm1(src)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    545             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    546         else:
--> 547             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    548         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    549             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/activation.py in forward(self, query, key, value, key_padding_mask, need_weights, attn_mask)
    781                 training=self.training,
    782                 key_padding_mask=key_padding_mask, need_weights=need_weights,
--> 783                 attn_mask=attn_mask)
    784 
    785 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in multi_head_attention_forward(query, key, value, embed_dim_to_check, num_heads, in_proj_weight, in_proj_bias, bias_k, bias_v, add_zero_attn, dropout_p, out_proj_weight, out_proj_bias, training, key_padding_mask, need_weights, attn_mask, use_separate_proj_weight, q_proj_weight, k_proj_weight, v_proj_weight, static_k, static_v)
   3250     if attn_mask is not None:
   3251         attn_mask = attn_mask.unsqueeze(0)
-> 3252         attn_output_weights += attn_mask
   3253 
   3254     if key_padding_mask is not None:

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (20) must match the size of tensor b (95) at non-singleton dimension 2
```

I was wondering if somebody could help me figure out this problem.

Thanks

Comment: You should make your titles more descriptive and to the point. Please fix it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The required shapes are shown in [`nn.Transformer.forward` - Shape](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Transformer.forward) (all building blocks of the transformer refer to it). The relevant ones for the encoder are:

- src: *(S, N, E)*
- src_mask: *(S, S)*
- src_key_padding_mask: *(N, S)*

where *S* is the sequence length, *N* the batch size and *E* the embedding dimension (number of features).

The padding mask should have shape *[95, 20]*, not *[20, 95]*. This assumes that your batch size is 95 and the sequence length is 20, but if that is the other way around, you would have to transpose the `src` instead.

Furthermore, when calling the encoder, you are not specifying the `src_key_padding_mask`, but rather the `src_mask`, as the signature of [`torch.nn.TransformerEncoder.forward`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.TransformerEncoder.forward) is:

```py
forward(src, mask=None, src_key_padding_mask=None)
```

The padding mask must be specified as the keyword argument `src_key_padding_mask` not as the second positional argument. And to avoid confusion, your `src_mask` should be renamed to `src_key_padding_mask`.

```py
src_key_padding_mask = torch.randint(0,2,(95, 20))
output =  encoder(src, src_key_padding_mask=src_key_padding_mask)
```