# Unexpected output when using src_key_padding_mask

Tags: pytorch

I think I understand the use of `src_key_padding_mask` thanks to [Difference between src_mask and src_key_padding_mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62170439/difference-between-src-mask-and-src-key-padding-mask). However, I was expecting the `src_key_padding_mask` to cause the output to be zero, or negative infinity for the masked values. Just wondering if I am using it correctly, or if I need to modify the following snippet.

Please note that I know I need to use positional encoding and that I have not used it on purpose.

```py
import random
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pad_sequence 

random.seed(42)
torch.manual_seed(42)
DIM = 5
BATCH = 2

x = [torch.randn(random.randint(1, 3), DIM) for _ in range(2)]
mask = pad_sequence([torch.LongTensor([1]*len(elem)) for elem in x]) == 0
padded_x = pad_sequence(x)

encoder_layer = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=DIM, nhead=1)
encoder = nn.TransformerEncoder(encoder_layer, num_layers=2).eval()

# the output of the following two are the same except for where it is masked. I was expecting zeros:
out1 = encoder(padded_x, src_key_padding_mask=mask.T)
out2 = encoder(padded_x)
```

Answer (score -1):

> I was expecting the `src_key_padding_mask` to cause the output to be zero, or negative infinity for the masked values.

The output values are still calculated, and are non-trivial for all time steps. It's just that none of the outputs should depend on the masked time steps (You can check that by tweaking the input and observing which outputs change)