# tgt_key_padding_mask in pytorch transformers BertModel

Tags: pytorch, padding, mask, bert-language-model, transformer-model

While going through the [transformer documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Transformer.html#torch.nn.Transformer) in PyTorch, I see that the tgt_key_padding_mask of shape (batch_size, tgt_seq_len) is used to indicate irrelevance of some parts of tgt because of padding. When I look at Pytorch's [BertModel implementation](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L865) from the transformers library, I don't see an option for such a mask in the forward function. How do I provide the tgt_key_padding_mask when using BertModel?

Notes: The top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62170439/difference-between-src-mask-and-src-key-padding-mask) explains what tgt_key_padding_mask is.

BertModel has the option to provide a head_mask, which is [multiplied with attention_probs](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L363) (after softmax, but before multiplying with the value). I haven't seen any mention of/ documentation regarding the expected shape of head_mask. It seems like it will be broadcasted to whatever shape necessary to multiply with attention_probs (which if of shape (batch_size, num_heads, query_seq_len=tgt_seq_len, key_seq_len=src_seq_len)), failing which a shape mismatch error will be triggered. I was thinking that I could simply use/ abuse this head_mask by passing my tgt_key_padding_mask via this. But is there another more appropriate way to specify a tgt_key_padding_mask while using BertModel?

Comment: The Bert implementation you linked is from Huggingface, which is a different entity from Pytorch. It's likely the Huggingface team did not implement the `tgt_key_padding_mask` feature.

Comment: Ok, any suggestions for a reliable PyTorch implementation of BERT, which implements tgt_key_padding? Just asking

Answer (score 1):

In BertModel, if attention_mask is passed as a 2D tensor, it is [assumed](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/modeling_utils.py#L915) to be the mask used to indicate which parts of the sequence are padding (and hence need to be ignored), which I (and the nn.Transformer [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Transformer.html)) refer to as tgt_key_padding_mask. In that case, the causal mask (tgt_mask, according to nn.Transformers documentation) is [automatically calculated](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/modeling_utils.py#L868) based on the sequence length, and is [combined](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/modeling_utils.py#L875) with the attention_mask passed. I wish this was documented somewhere.